# @types/passport version 1.0.5 generates new error: Type Authenticator does not satisfy the constraint IncomingMessage

Tags: typescript, passport.js, koa, koa-passport

I have a Koa.JS web app that uses Passport.JS for oAuth2 authentication. This web app is written in typescript. Here is the authentication code:

```
import { deserializeUser, serializeUser, use } from 'koa-passport';
import { Strategy, VerifyCallback } from 'passport-oauth2';
import config from 'config';
import { Authenticator } from 'passport';
const OAuth2Strategy = Strategy;
use(
  new OAuth2Strategy(
    config.get('oauth2'),
    (accessToken: string, refreshToken: string, profile: any, done: VerifyCallback): void => 
    {
      if (accessToken && refreshToken) {
        const tokens = { access_token: accessToken, refresh_token: refreshToken };
        done(null, tokens);
      } else {
        done(undefined, undefined, { message: 'An error occurred!' });
      }
    }
  )
);

serializeUser<Authenticator, Authenticator>(
  (user: Authenticator, done: (err: any, id?: Authenticator | undefined) => void): void => {
    done(null, user);
  }
);
```

The web app would compile fine with @types/passport 1.0.4, but generates new error when I upgrade the version of @types/passport to 1.0.5.

```
Type 'Authenticator<Handler, any, any, AuthenticateOptions>' does not satisfy the constraint 'IncomingMessage'.
Type 'Authenticator<Handler, any, any, AuthenticateOptions>' is missing the following properties from type 'IncomingMessage': aborted, httpVersion, httpVersionMajor, httpVersionMinor, and 45 more.

serializeUser<Authenticator, Authenticator>
```

Has anyone experienced this?

Comment: Don't pass type arguments explicitly.

Comment: Thank you @AluanHaddad for the prompt reply. It has helped to remove the type arguments. However, I am now getting a new error:

`(parameter) user: Express.User
Argument of type 'User' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Authenticator<Handler, any, any, AuthenticateOptions>'.
  Type 'User' is missing the following properties from type 'Authenticator<...>': ... .ts(2345)`


Here is new code:

`serializeUser(
  (user: Express.User, done: (err: any, id?: Authenticator | undefined) => void): void => {
    done(null, user);
  }
);`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a change in the Authenticator interface?
WHAT YOU SAY!?
Yes - an interface change with only a minor change in Version number!!!

I would expect that the serializeUser interface from koa-passport is probably out of sync with the updates made to passport... In my world - a breaking change to an interface usually means a major version change.

As below V1.0.4 of Passport allows the use of generic TUser

serializeUser<TUser, TID>(fn: (user: TUser, done: (err: any, id?: TID) => void) => void): void;

Now with V1.0.5 of passport the interface changed to restrict to Express.User.
serializeUser(fn: (user: Express.User, done: (err: any, id?: TID) => void) => void): void;